# Javascript - displaying a variable in alert box that's opened when user clicks on link?

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
var message = 'this is a message'
$('#textarea_feedback').html('<a href="javascript:;" onclick="alert()">Click me</a>')
```

What is the correct syntax for putting the `message` variable in the alert? Doing:

```
$('#textarea_feedback').html('<a href="javascript:;" onclick="alert(message)">Click me</a>')
```

Causes nothing to be alerted at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the `.html()` function you are passing a string, so you have to concatenate the value of the variable message, like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/number_phi/g306pewy/)

```
var message = 'this is a message'
$('#textarea_feedback').html('<a href="javascript:;" onclick="alert(\'' + message + '\')">Click me</a>');
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var message = 'this is a message';

$('#textarea_feedback').html('<a href="javascript:;" onclick="alert('+message+')">Click me</a>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="textarea_feedback"></div>
```

Comment: @Erazihel can you see the + operator for concatenation?

Comment: I've edited your answer and put it into a snippet, check out the result